# What is the distribution of digits throughout numbers called?

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm aware of [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) that covers the distribution of *leading* digits:

> Benford's law, also called the Newcomb–Benford law, the law of anomalous numbers, or the first-digit law, is an observation about the frequency distribution of leading digits in many real-life sets of numerical data.

However, I'm wondering if there's a name for the distribution of digits *throughout* numbers. For example, the distribution of digits for the number `89112374633510` is:

> 1: 21%
> 3: 14%
> 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9: 7% each

---

What is the distribution of digits, throughout a number called, and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: We don’t name everything, we name them as they become useful. I don’t see much use in this. It’s certainly a distribution, but is is unclear what use it might have.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm okay with that being the answer too. Just wanted to know if such a name existed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Interesting.  I am completely ignorant of the subject matter.  Given that, when I skimmed the cited article, I got the impression that election fraud analysis, based on the leading (presumably leftmost) digit is inappropriate for *small precincts*.  This leaves open the possibility that election fraud in small precincts might be detectable by examination of other than the leftmost digit.

Comment: Yes, but the expected distribution for the rightmost digits are just uniform - $1/10$ for each digit. And the overall distribution of digits $n\mapsto (p_0,p_1,\dots,p_9)$ aren’t going to be very interesting, because there is nothing about the order of them, and the interesting anomalies occur in the earlier digits. @user2661923

Comment: You could certainly find weirdness in data using the average of these vectors over the dataset. Too many $3$s, not enough $4$s. But it won’t be because it varies too far from an unusual distribution, but rather because it varies too far from a uniform distribution. @user2661923